# Read file output into a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have the output of a file that I would like to make a varabile in a batch program. How do I go about doing this? I would like to take the output of this, `php file.php` and put it into a variable named `%this%`. How do I do that?

[edit] Removed tags, this question is meant to provide an example for batch variable handling only. The fact that I used PHP was just an example, it could just as well be a python file that I'm reading the output from, or a regular executable.

Comment: Is the output single-line or multi-line?

Comment: @Andriy, it's single line.
@DOK, this is not a PHP question really, it's specific to batch. The fact that I used a php file was an example, it could just as well be a executable file. I also do not feel that the file-io tag fits this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('php file.php') do set "this=%%x"
```

Comment: Note that this will set `%this%` to the last non-empty line in the file.

Answer (score 5):

```
@ECHO OFF
php file.php > output.txt
set /p OUTPUT= < output.txt
del output.txt

echo %OUTPUT%
```

Comment: There is no faster way? Having to read the output to a file, then read that file again is silly. Thank you anyway, you've at least provided an answer that I can use.

Comment: @Mark: [Joey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559048/read-file-output-into-a-variable/6559719#6559719)'s answer then seems more suitable to your situation.